# log4net in WCF service hosted on a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, log4net

I have a WCF service which is hosted on a windows service.

Where should I put `XmlConfigurator.Configure();`?

In other applications, I can place it in `Application_Start()`

Can I place this in the OnStart() method of my windows service? Will I then able to instantiate the logger from my WCF service?

This is how I instantiate my logger:

```
private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

This is what I have in my windows service

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (AgentServiceHost != null)
        {
            AgentServiceHost.Close();
        }

        AgentServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CustoemrService));
        AgentServiceHost.Open();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put this piece of code in your AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Comment: For each project that I need log4net? i.e., if I need logging in my WCF service project, and in my Windows Service project, I have to add this line to both?

Comment: By default there's no AssemblyInfo.cs in my WCF service or Windows service project

Comment: Yes, AssemblyInfo.cs is under the Properties node in Solution Explorer. Visual Studio creates this file in every project by default.
This should be included only in the project that has the entry point of your code, in this case in both the WCF Service and your Win Service

Comment: AssemblyInfo is only created for winforms applications

Comment: No, you're wrong. AssemblyInfo is created by default in every project.
http://postimg.org/image/pvdczfzcx/
And even so, it can be added manually ;-)